# Efficiency: How many MySQL rows should I pull at a time?

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now, I have a script that does the following in python:

```
infinite loop:
     select 1 row from MySQL
     works with row data
     updates 1 row if needed in MySQL (<10% of the time)
```

Would selecting and updating more than 1 row at a time speed up my script and process more rows? If so, how many rows should I pull down? I have a small VPS with 512 MB RAM. Would 1000 rows at a time be too many? Too little?

The new script logic would be:

```
infinite loop:
    select 1000 rows from MySQL
    loop 1000 times:
        work with row data
        appends mysql statement to string if update is required
    runs the single update statement containing 10-50 commands
```

The new logic would have 1 big select request and 1 big update request. Would this be better than many little select and update requests?

I couldn't find much info about this. Thanks so much!

Comment: I would suggest testing and finding out how many to pull works best with your system.

Comment: But multiple rows is without doubt more efficiency than 1 by 1?

Comment: How many rows exist you need to check? We don't have much frame of reference here.

Comment: I'm checking about 1 million rows right now, and growing. When it's done, it will start over from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you want to make as few calls to the database as you possibly can. As far as how many records to get per call is all up to your system.

My method is to just mess around with the number until I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance, no assumptions should be made. You should measure things in order to make a decision. You should define **performance goals** and then test your system. I would suggest using some king of **load test** tools like [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html) or [hammerdb](http://hammerora.sourceforge.net/). If you have problems, then you can use some kind of **profiler** like [neor](http://www.profilesql.com/).

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try using load tests because at the end it depends on how you want to measure things but in my opinion fetching more rows at a time is more efficient because if you fetch a row that is last in the table and fetch the row again that is second last, then you loop two times in the table while if you you fetch multiple rows at a time then you just loop through once and get all the rows.

Hope I helped